# RODBC Connection Failed

Tags: asp.net, r, visual-studio-2015, sql-server-2014, rodbc

I'm aware that this has been asked before, but none of the solutions have worked for me.

I'm trying to create a connection between R and a SQL Server '14 Database that I'm developing with Visual Studio 2015 for an ASP.NET project. I've searched through all the suggested solutions to this and have tried everything I can think of, but I continue to get error messages that say the connection has failed.

This is my latest attempt:

```
cn<-odbcDriverConnect('driver={SQL Server};server="B8Q4VLD,MSSQLSERVER,1433";database=Northwind;trusted_connection=true')

> cn<-odbcDriverConnect('driver={SQL Server};server="B8Q4VLD,MSSQLSERVER,1433";database=Northwind;trusted_connection=true')
```

> ```
> Warning messages:
> 1: In odbcDriverConnect("driver={SQL Server};server=\"B8Q4VLD,MSSQLSERVER,1433\";database=Northwind;trusted_connection=true") :
>   [RODBC] ERROR: state 08001, code 17, message [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][DBNETLIB]SQL Server does not exist or access denied.
> 2: In odbcDriverConnect("driver={SQL Server};server=\"B8Q4VLD,MSSQLSERVER,1433\";database=Northwind;trusted_connection=true") :
>   [RODBC] ERROR: state 01000, code 53, message [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][DBNETLIB]ConnectionOpen (Connect()).
> 3: In odbcDriverConnect("driver={SQL Server};server=\"B8Q4VLD,MSSQLSERVER,1433\";database=Northwind;trusted_connection=true") :
>   ODBC connection failed
> Server Name: DESKTOP-B8Q4VLD\Tracey
> Instance Name: MSSQLSERVER
> Port Number: 1433
> ```

I've also tried including my username and ID instead of the trusted connection part. i.e. uid=Tracey;pwd=****

```
   > cn<-odbcDriverConnect('driver={SQL Server};server="B8Q4VLD,MSSQLSERVER,1433";database=Northwind;uid=Tracey;pwd=****')
```

> ```
> Warning messages:
> 1: In odbcDriverConnect("driver={SQL Server};server=\"B8Q4VLD,MSSQLSERVER,1433\";database=Northwind;uid=Tracey;pwd=****") :
>   [RODBC] ERROR: state 08001, code 17, message [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][DBNETLIB]SQL Server does not exist or access denied.
> 2: In odbcDriverConnect("driver={SQL Server};server=\"B8Q4VLD,MSSQLSERVER,1433\";database=Northwind;uid=Tracey;pwd=****") :
>   [RODBC] ERROR: state 01000, code 53, message [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][DBNETLIB]ConnectionOpen (Connect()).
> 3: In odbcDriverConnect("driver={SQL Server};server=\"B8Q4VLD,MSSQLSERVER,1433\";database=Northwind;uid=Tracey;pwd=Tracey") :
>   ODBC connection failed
> ```

I've set the ENV PATH to R correctly.

Found a [recent article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt709082.aspx) that says something about sep=" "... though not sure what this is.

Any suggestion is welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the server. Because it's hosted locally, it needed to be '**localhost**'.

Checking the connection via cmd helped me work it out. C:\Users\Username>**SQLCMD -L**

And I used [this tutorial](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/reporting-services/making-data-analytics-simpler-sql-server-and-r/) to find the correct syntax.

```
cn<-odbcDriverConnect(connection="driver={SQL Server};server=localhost;database=Northwind;Trusted_Connection=true;")
dataFetchEUR <- sqlFetch(cn, 'Customers', colnames=FALSE,
                         rownames = TRUE)
```